# PKPaymentButton change style after tap

Tags: swift, button, applepay

I'm trying to implement applePayButton with PKPaymentButton.
I declarated  it:

```
 private var applePayBtn = PKPaymentButton.init(paymentButtonType: .plain, paymentButtonStyle: .black)
```

after tap on this button I need to change the style of button  (change color to white)

I tried to make it:

```
self.applePayBtn = .init(paymentButtonType: .plain, paymentButtonStyle: .whiteOutline)
```

but it isn't work. maybe someone know, how to change style of PKPaymentButton in runtime. thanks for answer.

Comment: `PKPaymentButton` extends `UIButton`/`NSButton`. Use the standard button APIs to change its style as needed.